# Функция не возвращает ссылку

Tags: c++, функции, stl, map

Есть следующая функция, она должна возвращать ссылку на значение ключа, если ключ такой существует в словаре, иначе выбрасывать исключение, но почему-то она возвращает вместо ссылки значение. Почему так происходит?

```
template<class K, class V> V& GetRefStrict(map<K, V> container, const K& key) {
    if(auto it = container.find(key); it != container.end()) {
        return it->second;
    }
    throw runtime_error("Unfortunately this key didn't finded");
}

int main() {
    map<int, string> m = {{0, "value"}};
    string& item = GetRefStrict(m, 0);
    item = "newvalue";
    cout << m[0] << endl; // returns value instead newvalue
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Брр! Ссылку на переменную, которая удаляется при выходе из функции? У вас программа вообще свалиться должна, по-хорошему...

Вы передаете `map` по значению, создается копия, которая умирает при выходе из функции, итератор указывает в не пойми куда, вы меняете что-то где-то... Но только не в вашем исходном `m`. Делайте так:

```
GetRefStrict(map<K, V>& container,
```

Обратите внимание на **`&`**.

Comment: Спасибо, да, забыл принять по ссылке контейнер